# How to execute dynamic SQL via linked server to Azure SQL Database

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database

We are 'starting' from an on prem SQL Server instance, the linked server being an Azure SQL Database.
Creating a table on a linked server is not all that difficult, BUT there isn't a lot of documentation on how to do it when the linked server is a Azure SQL single database. I get the following error:

> Msg 40515, Level 16, State 2
> Reference to database and/or server name in 'master.dbo.sp_executesql' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.

```
DECLARE @LinkedServer sysname = N'MyAzureSQLDatabaseLinkedServer',
        @SQL nvarchar(max);


SELECT @SQL = 'EXEC ' + @LinkedServer + '.' + 'master.dbo.sp_executesql '
    + 'CREATE TABLE dbo.flarb(splort int);';

--PRINT @SQL
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL
```

Comment: don't use sys with sp_executesql

Comment: That code does far more than utlise a linked server. I suggest if you are using linked servers/cross database in Azure SQL, see if you can not do it that way

Comment: @nbk help me out, because I'm not quite sure what you mean. [sys, dbo, or no schema all work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXVhn.png), so how would removing `sys` help the OP?

Comment: hello Aaron & others, sorry the initial formulation of my question being at bit unclear (it was after a long day). Indeed linked servers on Azure SQL are no-go, I'm glad you found it after a few reads

Answer (score 2):

The problem is simpler than I thought. I read the question three times and was convinced you thought you had created a linked server *inside Azure SQL Database* to *some other server*, which [isn't possible, according to the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/linked-servers-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver16):

> Linked servers are available in SQL Server Database Engine and Azure SQL Managed Instance. They are not enabled in Azure SQL Database singleton and elastic pools.

On the fourth read, the elevator door finally opened, and I realized you are trying to dynamically re-create a table from a local instance, via a linked server, on your Azure SQL Database. You have, essentially:

```
EXEC AzureLink.master.dbo.sp_executesql N'SELECT DB_NAME();';
```

But even that simple command will fail, with the same error (so it doesn't involve table creation). Try instead:

```
EXEC AzureLink..sys.sp_executesql N'SELECT DB_NAME();';
--------------^^-- leave database out!
```

The error message is actually very accurate about what is happening: you can't mention `master`. The syntax here still works because *if you leave the database name out of the 4-part name*, it defaults to the catalog defined in your linked server, which shouldn't be `master` (but that wouldn't make this work, either, as the command is being rejected at parse time).

I also think your life would be easier if, instead of putting the linked server name dynamically into your SQL statement and then having to have nested dynamic SQL, you simply use a variable that concatenates the linked server name with `sp_executsql`:

```
DECLARE @context nvarchar(519) = QUOTENAME(@LinkedServer)
  + N'..sys.sp_executesql';

SET @sql = N'SELECT DB_NAME();';

EXEC @context @sql;
```

I talk about [this technique in more detail here](https://sqlblog.org/2022/10/11/t-sql-tuesday-155-do-x-to-all-the-dbs). And I think it will help because I'm pretty sure once you get past the syntax issue, you're going to find that this isn't going to work exactly like you thought:

```
SELECT @SQL = N'EXEC ' + @LinkedServer 
    + '..sys.sp_executesql '
    + 'CREATE TABLE ' + @object_name ...
```

Since `sp_executesql` takes a *string*, that needs to start with a doubled-up apostrophe:

```
SELECT @SQL = N'EXEC ' + @LinkedServer 
    + '..sys.sp_executesql '
    + 'N''CREATE TABLE ' + @object_name ...
```

And if anything further on in `@SQL` needs to pass an apostrophe, you need to pass 4 (`''''`), and then 8, and then 16... nesting gets real ugly, real fast, and using `char(39)` instead only helps so much.

So with the right `@context` populated, now you can just express it this way, and not have to worry about any nesting:

```
SELECT @SQL = N'CREATE TABLE ...';

EXEC @context @SQL;
```

Comment: It was in the nuances such as leaving out the database part. Thanks a lot for the eye opening response